# Creating a NuGet package out of two projects, ends up with missing references

Tags: c#, nuget, nuget-package

I have a `MailService` package that uses Azure queues. I have put the queue related logic in a separate project. I'm using this in my pipeline to create a package that has both projects:

```
  - task: NuGetCommand@2
    displayName: "Pack MailService"
    inputs:
      command: 'pack'
      packagesToPack: '**/Testing.MailService.csproj'
      packDestination: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
      versioningScheme: 'off'
      allowPackageConflicts: true
      includeReferencedProjects: true
```

This is how the generated package [looks like in dotPeek](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eg8TJ.png).
As you can see the main package `MailService` references the queue one. The problem is that when I try using it in a different solution, I get the exception that `Azure.Storage.Queues` is not found. I do see that it exists in the references of the `Storage.Queues` project which is referenced by the first one. What exactly is the problem here?

These are my two project files

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <Version>1.0.0</Version>
  </PropertyGroup>
  
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="7.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="7.0.3">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="7.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions" Version="7.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Options.DataAnnotations" Version="7.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
  
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Testing.Storage.Queues\Testing.Storage.Queues.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
        <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
        <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="Azure.Storage.Queues" Version="12.13.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Options" Version="7.0.1" />
        <PackageReference Include="Testing.Utilities.OperationResult" Version="1.4.6" />
    </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

I did try this [workaround](https://github.com/nuget/home/issues/3891#issuecomment-377319939). However, that broke my Azure pipeline with:

```
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.201\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2352,5): warning MSB3277: Found conflicts between different versions of "Azure.Core" that could not be resolved. [D:\a\1\s\src\Infrastructure\Testing.Functions\Testing.Functions.csproj]

C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.201\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2352,5): warning MSB3277: There was a conflict between "Azure.Core, Version=1.24.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=92742159e12e44c8" and "Azure.Core, Version=1.28.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=92742159e12e44c8". [D:\a\1\s\src\Infrastructure\Testing.Functions\Testing.Functions.csproj]

C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.201\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2352,5): warning MSB3277:         C:\Users\VssAdministrator\.nuget\packages\azure.core\1.24.0\lib\net5.0\Azure.Core.dll [D:\a\1\s\src\Infrastructure\Testing.Functions\Testing.Functions.csproj]
```

Comment: Azure Pipeline's `NuGetCommand` command uses nuget.exe, but `nuget.exe pack` doesn't support SDK style projects (I'm reasonably confident there are warnings in the docs).  You should replace the NuGetCommand task with a script task and just run `dotnet pack path\to\Test.MailProj.csproj` instead.

Comment: Hey, sorry for the late reply. While you are correct that `NuGetCommand` doesn't support SDK style projects, that is not the problem. I did forget to mention that I have `NUGET_ENABLE_LEGACY_CSPROJ_PACK: true` which makes the `NuGetCommand` run fine. The problem is within the generated package. When I try using it I keep on getting the exception about `Azure.Storage.Queues` not found.

Comment: NUGET_ENABLE_LEGACY_CSPROJ_PACK only suppresses the error messge, it doesn't make nuget.exe magically support SDK style projects. The dependencies is exactly what we (I work for NuGet) mean when we say nuget.exe doesn't support PackageReference, and SDK style projects are always PackageReference, never packages.config. nuget.exe pack only knows how to determine dependencies from packages.config. You need to switch to MSBuild pack, for example `dotnet pack`.

Comment: Alright, I got it working by using `dotnet pack` and the workaround I mentioned. Thanks for the help.